# android: String value match another String value using operand == not working?

Tags: java, android

Hopefully this is an easy fix, but for the moment is is boggling me (Actionscript programmer new to Java programming).

I have a string variable coming from getExtra that I am comparing to a static sting in an if statement:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
dir = extras.getString("com.activity.Dir");
```

Then I am utilizing this in an if statement

```
if (dir == "content"){
    // load page content
} else {
    // load a menu
}
```

I am Toasting the value of dir on the line before it and regardless of the value it will not hit the == statement; ie: if dir == "content", it hits the else; if dir == "foo", it hits the else, etc.

I tried placing dir into another String var and used .toString();

```
String directive = dir.toString();
```

That does the same thing. What am I missing here?

SOLVED: Used dir.equals("content");
// Thanks for you being patient with me SO!

Comment: is it comparing by reference instead of value? What about `dir.equals("content")`?

Comment: That solved it. wow... I am new to Java (web developer proficient with JS and AS) I really need to take a class. Suggest that as a solution and I will mark it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Take one of the other answers, I've never programmed for Android before which is why I left that as a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must not compare strings via `==`, but via `.equals()`

Comment: Ah, that goes against everything I've been taught in other programming languages. Thanks! Will mark as solved.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are Objects, and to do correct Object equality comparisions, you need to use

```
dir.equals("content");
```

or better yet (to avoid possible null pointer exceptions)

```
"content".equals(dir);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use equals for Strings on Java.

2 tips:

- Add the string you know it isn't null to avoid nullpointers. Ex: "compare".equals(string)
- Use equalsIgnoreCase() instead of equals if you wish to compare strings and ignore the case differences.

Answer (score 1):

Use the equals method instead of ==

Answer (score 0):

`"vuqar"=="vuqar"` or `"vuqar"!="vuqar"` not works correct

You have to use

```
if(vuqar.equals("vuqar")){//action}
```

OR

```
if(!"vuqar".equals("vuqar")){//action}
```